# MSVC: Why are functions containing basic QString operations not inlined?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

When compiling this sample with MSVC ([full source](https://bitbucket.org/ens_/qstring_inline/src))

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

static __forceinline QString makeString() {
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    QString str = makeString();
    qDebug() << str;
    return 0;
}
```

The following warning is emitted:

```
function 'QString makeString(void)' marked as __forceinline not inlined
```

For compiling, I'm using the default qmake settings (plus `-W4` warnings):

```
cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -O2 -MD -GR -W4 -EHsc
-w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4127 -w34100
-DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG
-IC:\home\dev\qstring_inline -I. -I..\..\qt\qt_5.5.1\build\qtbase\include -I..\..\qt\qt_5.5.1\build\qtbase\include\QtGui -I..\..\qt\qt_5.5.1\build\qtbase\include\QtCore -Irelease -Ie:\builds\qt\qt_5.5.1\qt5\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Forelease\ @C:\Users\ens\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.17344.16.jom
main.cc
```

I've reproduced this issue with `Qt 5.5.1`, `Qt 5.4` and `VS 2015 Update 1, 64-bit MSVC`, `VS 2013 Update 5, 64-bit MSVC`.

Checking the assembly confirms that makeString() is indeed generated and called.

Both the default constructor ([code browser](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstring.h.html#_ZN7QStringC1Ev)) ...

```
inline QString::QString() Q_DECL_NOTHROW : d(Data::sharedNull()) {}
```

... and the rvalue copy constructor ([code browser](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstring.h.html#_ZN7QStringC1EOS_))

```
inline QString(QString && other) Q_DECL_NOTHROW : d(other.d) { other.d = Data::sharedNull(); }
```

are very simple.
What could prevent makeString() from being inlined?

Comment: Have you look at asm to check that there is indeed a call to `makeString`. Maybe the call is ellided with constructor and RVO but not marked as *inlined*.

Comment: Just a suspicion, but that `sharedNull` thing ends up using a static character array in `QArrayData` - the compiler might prefer not to inline and have lots of addresses to that array to patch in at link time, or load time if it ends up being in a shared object....

Comment: @Jarod42, yes, makeString is generated and called. I've added this to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is unable to inline a function that has a return type with a nontrivial destructor.  This is a limitation of the compiler; the compiler team is looking at improving this for a future release.